# C# Best way to degrade from a database query

Tags: c#, exception

I have taught myself C# and at the moment I am developing a try catch block. It is to write to a database.

```
    try
    {
        //Write to Database
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //report issue
        //close connection
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //report issue
        //close connection
    }
    finally
    {
        //close connection
    }
```

Is there any other exception that should be checked for?

Should I check also in case the connection String fails?

Or would the SQLException be good enough on its own?

Comment: Instead of explicitly closing a connection in the `finally` just put the connection inside a `using` block instead. Also, if you did close it in the finally you don't need to close it in the `catch` the `finally` still runs even if you go to a `catch` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `using` blocks around the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` (if applicable) then you don't need an explicit `try/catch` to ensure that anything is disposed.

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
using(var command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection)
{
    //etc
}
```

To specifically answer your question about catching a `SqlException` or an `Exception`, the answer is - yes, catch the `SqlException` first *if* you would do something differently as a result of a `SqlException` vs. any other exception. But you probably wouldn't. There's probably no reason to, so no, I wouldn't bother with a separate catch just for the `SqlException`. Only do it if you need it.

That leaves the question - do you actually need to catch any exceptions in this method at all? The answer is probably not. If an exception is thrown, `using` will dispose whatever needs disposing, then the exception can just bubble up to whatever method called it. At some point you'll want to log it, but you don't need logging at every layer in every method. For example, if it's a WCF service, you could just log exceptions thrown when a service method is called.

There could be scenarios where you need to catch the exception so that you can respond by doing something differently. Perhaps you're querying for several data sets, and if one fails you can just log the error and return an empty result rather than causing a downstream failure. But that's not too often.

Something else worth looking at is AOP - [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net). Many methods need exception logging, but it's not really the function of those classes. So there are ways to keep that unrelated but necessary code out of most of your classes and methods. I linked to PostSharp but personally I use [Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/) because it provides both dependency injection and interceptors which wrap method  calls with things like exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Exception class is a grneric class and it will catch all exceptions